# Is it possible to do edit and delete options in one jsp page in java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

Here i am using HTML Table for display all the records with edit and delete columns i need to do edit and delete only one jsp page but how can i do this in java script or jquery.

my code:

```
<%
Connection con = null;     
int sumcount=0;
Statement st;
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    SQLServerDataSource ds = new SQLServerDataSource();              
      con = ds.getConnection();
      st=con.createStatement(); 

String query = "select * from Users";
st = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
%>
<%
while(rs.next()){
%>
<tr><td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" style="background-color:#ff6347;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="editRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
<td><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete" style="background-color:#ff6347;font-weight:bold;color:#ffffff;" onclick="deleteRecord(<%=rs.getString(1)%>);" ></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(1)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(3)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(4)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(5)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(6)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getInt(7)%></td>
<td><%=rs.getString(8)%></td></tr>
<%
}
%>
<%
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
</table>
```

when i click edit button in table all corresponding values are insert data into corresponding text but it do in one page only i need to do all operations is it possible to do

Comment: Show the code of the `editRecord()` and `deleteRecord()` Javascript functions.

Comment: I did two jsp pages those two methods

Answer (score 0):

If your delete method gets a parameter you could bind your method into a button that deletes the current row of the table.

JSP:

```
<a href="delete.do?id=<%=user.getUserName()%>">
   <button class="edit-button">
      Your Code
   </button>
</a>
```

To set the parameter inside your method:

```
String username = request.getParameter("id");
```

This makes your page get the data you want (username in this case) from the current row where the button is and then pass the parameter to the method that will delete his row.